# Routing messages between queue managers using websphere message broker

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

How can I use WebSphere Message broker instance to route messages between queues residing in two queue managers. The message broker instance can only be associated with one queue manager during creation time. So I create an MQInputNode and put messages to the specific source queue. My concern is to route this message to second queue residing in another queue manager using the same broker instance. How? I am using WebSphere Message Broker version 8.0.0.8. Not yet into IIB.

Comment: What version of IIB are you running?  At v10 you can create MQOutputNodes that connect as a MQ client to any queue manager, in fact you no longer need a local queue manager for the IIB broker to run against.  If you are not yet at that version then you can simply setup QREMOTE objects on the local queue manager that point to the remote queue manager, of course you need connectivity to the remote queue manager MQ Sender channel to a MQ Receiver channel.  Please edit your question to provide some more detail of your env.

Comment: So does IIB has MQInputNodes as well which can connect as client to any queue manager?

Comment: Yes, with IIB 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple and efficient way of doing it.

Suppose, your broker is on QM1. You have a local queue in QM2 named LQ_QM2.
And you want the messages to go to LQ_QM2. Follow below steps:

> 1. At QM1, create a local queue of usage 'Transmission'. Let us name this transmission queue as "QM2".
> 2. At QM1, create a sender channel named "QM1.QM2" with proper connection name (Contains host(port) of target queue manager, for eg
>      10.1.5.2(1144)) and set transmission queue as QM2 (The one we created in step 1).
> 3. Create a receiver channel at QM2 named "QM1.QM2).
> 4. Now create a remote queue definition at QM1. Let's name it as RQ_LQ_QM2. Set remote queue property as LQ_QM2 and transmission queue
>      as QM2 and remote queue manager as QM2.
> 5. The messages which you want to send to the queue LQ_QM2 can now be written by the broker to RQ_LQ_QM2 in QM1 itself.

*If you can't do the above MQ stuff and must use only Message broker capability then the way of doing it in WMB 8 would be to use Java and write an MQ client code using the MQ API libraries. You will then establish remote connection with the remote queue manager using SVRCONN channel and put messages on the remote queue manager's queue.*